# Power outage in different rooms In the home

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Different rooms in my home will lose power at random times. Most of the time it is on the left side of the house where my children have their bedroom and bathroom. The circuit breaker never trips. However, once I turn off the circuit breaker for that area, wait a few minutes, and then turn it back on. Usually the light will be OK. Sometimes it will take longer for it to come back on. I had a electrician stop by and not return due to hurricane Laura. He thought that one of the 20 amp circuit breakers needed to be replaced with a Homeline 30 amp/120V/GFCI circuit breaker. This circuit breaker happens to control two of my children’s bedrooms. There is no single pole, 30 amp Homeline circuit breaker. I had another person replace the existing 20 amp circuit breaker with a brand new Homeline 20 amp/GFCI circuit breaker. Less than two hours later the power in various rooms shut off. The kitchen and laundry room were perfectly fine. But now my bedroom and bathroom went out which is located on the opposite side of the house. And two out of my four bedrooms for my kids power went out along with her bathroom. Plus the lights for the front porch and back patio. I flipped all the circuit breakers and they came back on a few minutes later.

The night prior, the lights in my kids restroom started to dim and come back on off and on prior to us going to bed. It was fine the next morning. Also, that morning the tv in the living room would randomly shut off and come back on along with the cable box. I’m afraid and have no idea what is going on. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Sounds like a call to ghostbusters is in order.  Seriously though, are you in the US?  These are suggestions (hence not posted as answer).  Get *any* reputable electrician in there to look at this.  It could be all of your breakers are bad (not likely), that the main breaker is bad (more likely), that you have a bad/broken connection going into your main breaker (slightly less likely), or the service going into your house is damaged (probably most likely).  If it is the service, then you power company will fix for free.

Comment: Replacing a 20a breaker for regular, in-house light & receptacle circuit is _**highly**_ likely to be a _VERY_ bad idea. The breaker amperage is determined by the size of the wires in the wall, not convenience or a hunch.

Comment: Can you map the failing circuits to specific breakers in the panel? Can you post photos of your electrical panel for that matter?

Comment: Just to echo, an "electrician" that suggests upsizing a 20a breaker to a 30a breaker is very very very unlikely to be competent.

Comment: I seriously need you to either learn to measure voltages with a voltmeter, or obtain a gadget called a "Kill-a-Watt" (or competitor) from a home store.  I want you to plug it into various outlets and take note of the voltages.  Any which are below 120V are of concern, but any *above* 120V are of much greater concern.  Also, I'd like you to turn off all 240V loads (handle tied double breakers) while testing, in particular note if any circuits work with 240V breakers on, yet fail with them off.  Fair chance this is a power company problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should call a qualified electrician.
You may be losing one phase feeding the breaker box due to a loose connection.
Or you could have a loose connection in a junction box somewhere.
Both can cause connections to overheat and cause a fire so get this addressed

Comment: Here on DIY.se, we don't knee-jerk every answer to "call an electrician".  Here we have a situation that's most likely in the power company's bailiwick, qualifies as an actual "roll the truck right now" outage... and will be fixed in an hour for free.  Hiring an electrician only adds days and $100++ to the process, since the answer will still be "call the PoCo".  Also OP has already called an electrician twice.

Comment: My apologies but as a Journeyman electrician of IBEW local 5 in Pittsburgh for many years the life and safety of the homeowner is always on my mind.

Comment: The [forum policy on this](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/hire-a-professional-answers/1164#1164) is clear, however.  This is a DIY site, and we're here to help people DIY.

Answer (score 0):

That must be very scary!  Sorry you are going thru this. I sounds like you have problems on multiple circuits.  If it was just one circuit (breaker), I'd say you have a bad connection in an outlet someplace. The outlets where you just press the wire in the back (backstabs), are notorious for failing. The connection is so poor that under some conditions, they heat up, loose the connection, cool down and then work again.   But since it sounds like you are experiencing this throughout the house, you have a supply problem. Might be a bad connection on your main feeds, or even at the power company transformer, or meter base.

You need to get this checked out by the power company and a competent electrician. You have a dangerous situation on your hands.

Comment: You reminded me of something George (mentioning the backstabs heating etc).  The OP needs to check what kind of wire is in the house (copper or aluminum).  All aluminum should be replaced with copper because the aluminum will heat up and work itself loose.

Comment: We should also learn what is being used at the time of the failures.  Space heaters? Hair dryers, toasters, coffee maker, microwave, etc.   See if there is a pattern.

Comment: @tnknepp aluminum, _properly_ connected is just fine.